# Content Hugging Priority Not working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-autolayout

I have a view whose height is directly proportional to the height of the parent view. Within the view there are two buttons and a spacer view. I want the heights of buttons to increase first and then the height of spacer view to increase with lower priority. For this purpose I have set the heights of buttons equal, and given two additional constraints to the first button i.e **30 <= height <= 50**. I have assigned spacer view height **>= 30.** Now if extra space is available, I want the buttons to grow up-to the size of **50** and if still some space is available I would like the spacer view to fill-up the remaining area. To achieve this I have given the buttons a content hugging **priority(vertical)  200** and the spacer view has a higher content hugging **priority(vertical) 300**. But this is not working as expected. Am I missing or doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: What is in the spacer view? Content hugging works with the intrinsicContentSize and an empty UIView has a content size of (0,0)

Comment: I have kept the spacer views empty.

Comment: Then content hugging will be ineffective as there is no content to hug

Comment: So any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Set a lower priority height constraint on your spacer view?

Comment: Worked for now, although I have fixed the button height and the spacer view is adjusted according to view height. Thanks for the suggestions.